# IBM Watson Natural Language Understanding - Too Many Request Error

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-nlu

I am using IBM Watson Natural Language Understanding Service via Node SDK for Text Analysis. I have an Array of sentences with length nearly 20 to 30. When I tried to iterate through the Array and Call NLU Analyze API I am getting `Error : Too Many Request`.

There is no API available for Bulk process of text analysis and I don't see any limit in NLU Service Documentation. I am using Standard Plan.

Is there any way to get rid of this error? I want to analyze an Array of sentences.

Error Log :

```
Error: Too Many Requests
at Request._callback (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/watson-developer-cloud/lib/requestwrapper.js:99:21)
at Request.self.callback (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
at Request.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1056:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

### Update:

Adding Source Code :

```
segmentList.forEach((segment) => {
    var params = {
        text: segment,
        features: {
            keywords: {
                sentiment: false
            },
            sentiment: {
                document: true
            }
        }
    };
    logger.info("Analyse Segment : " + segment);
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        NLUService.analyze(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err != null) {
                logger.error(err.stack);
            }
            ctr += 1;
            // Inserting data.sentiment.document.score to Database   
            .
            .
            .           
            if (ctr == callSegments.length)
                resolve();
        });
    }).then(() => resolve());
});
```

Comment: May you please edit and add your source code? `429 Too Many Requests`, The service is throttling your request because your IBM Cloud ID submitted more than 1200 requests per minute.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know after using the Natural Language Understanding service, there seems to be a limitation of 20 concurrent requests.

You need to make sure you don't send more than 20 requests at the same time.
If you look at [this blog](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/run-n-promises-in-parallel/) post you will see some patterns of how you can run N promises in parallel.

Comment: I don't anything like that in their documentation.!

Comment: I don't think it's documented

Comment: I'll pass this issue onto the service documentation team.